# Check-in (via SVN version-control) of whole package tree with Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Earlier versions of EA made a single svn commit for each package when I call "check-in whole package tree" from the context menu in the model tree. Sometimes this means >20 revisions at once if the tree consists of many packages. But so many revisions for one check-in is not what I want, it should be 1 svn commit for all together.

Is it still that way in Enterprise Architect 14.x?

Comment: I don't hink they changed anything to the way version control works in v14.

Comment: Comfortability of the version control system for the UML model a critical acceptance topic for the whole tool.

Comment: Well, if you think so. I don't. I'm rather praying to not use version control like for coding (since a model is NOT code). Rather to just create nightly snapshots (which otherwise can be accomplished via database backups as well).